# Consuming a web service with Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin Forms, and I have a few questions.

1. What's the Portable project that appears in demos and tutorials? My project from scratch is not called Portable.

[image]

2. Must I make my own service interface? After I add the Web reference, References.cs has generated classes and methods. Why not just use those methods directly?

Comment: Looks like you created an Xamarin Forms project that has a shared class instead of one with a standard or portable class library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When creating the app, make sure you select *Xamarin.Forms*, as well as *Portable Class Library*.

The Portable project (aka Portable Class Library, or PCL) is where the shared code goes for your Xamarin.Forms app. For example, your UI, Models, and View Models will go into that project. You mainly need to worry about the iOS and Android projects for Custom Renderers and Dependency Services, to create custom UI or platform-specific functionality that Xamarin.Forms can't do.

As for consuming the service, its not necessary to create a service interface (I assume its a RESTful service), but it will help you in being able to use the service more easily.